# BotDetect Captcha Error Message is not displaying ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, captcha, botdetect

I have integrated the BotDetect Captcha in to my ASP.NET MVC form and I can not get the validation message to display when the user enters the incorrect Captcha value.

What do I need to change to get the validation message to display?

**Edit** - I added the `Html.BeginForm` portion of the view to indicate that the post back is going to a different action in the controller.

Source Code - View

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Contact", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = 'multipart/form-data' }))
{
    @{ 
        MvcCaptcha contactCaptcha = new MvcCaptcha("ContactCaptcha");
        contactCaptcha.UserInputID = "ContactCaptchaCode";
    }
    To prevent spam, we utilize a verification code system.  Please enter the code as it is shown in the box below.<br />
    @Html.Captcha(contactCaptcha)<br />
    Code:<br />
    @Html.TextBox("ContactCaptchaCode", string.Empty, new { @class = "form-   control", @style = "width: 200px" })                
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align: right">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn-default" />
            @Html.ValidationMessage("ContactCaptchaCode", new { @class = "text-danger" }) 
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Source Code - Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[CaptchaValidation("ContactCaptchaCode", "ContactCaptcha", "Please enter the correct CAPTCHA code.")]
public ActionResult Create(Models.Contact formContact)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //do stuff here is correct captcha value
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that `ModelState` is always valid even when you enter an incorrect value?

Comment: If it is invalid, then all you should need is `else { return View(formContact); }` to return the view and display the error message

Comment: @StephenMuecke No, ModelState is valid when they enter a correct CAPTCHA code, when they enter an invalid CAPTCHA code it prevents the form from being processed and `ModelState.IsValid = false`

Comment: And when you return the view if `ModelState` is invalid, are you saying the message is not displayed?

Answer (score 1):

you have to add `!ModelState.IsValid` if `false` then return to the view because in your code if model is invalid do nothing and thats not how validation works. so do something like this

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[CaptchaValidation("ContactCaptchaCode", "ContactCaptcha", "Please enter the correct CAPTCHA code.")]
public ActionResult Create(Models.Contact formContact)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
      return view(formContact);
  }

    //if valid do your code here
}
```

now if you place a break point you will see `ModelState` will have `keys` and `values` if any validation fails and when you do `return view(formContact);` it will return to the view with validation messages and it will match key and display the error message e.g let suppose i have

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("ContactCaptchaCode");
```

if validation fails for this property `modelstate` will have `key=ContactCaptchaCode` and `value=Please enter the correct CAPTCHA code.`

Comment: One thing I should mention, I am using the `Html.BeginForm` overload where I explicitly configure the route after form submission.  i.e. `("Create", "Contact", FormMethod.Post)`.  Would this have an impact on the behavior of the CAPTCHA validation?